# notFound() route for Micro Phalcon app

Tags: php, routes, phalcon

I've set up a Micro app to function as a CMS. So there will be potentially infinite possible routes, that I want to all direct to my Index handler.

I've set up my index.php file like so:

```
$App = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Micro;
$App->setDI($DI);
$App->notFound(function(){
    $Index = new \Handler\Index();
    $Index->handle();
});

$App->handle();
```

When I go to `www.site.com/dev/`, which is the homepage, everything works fine. `$Index->handle()` gets called.

However, when I go to a sub-page like `www.site.com/dev/blah`, I get `Fatal error: Uncaught Phalcon\Mvc\Micro\Exception: Matched route doesn't have an associated handler`. Well I haven't set up any routes, so everything should be going to the notFound handler.

What am I missing?

Comment: no wildcard routing in phalcon?

Comment: @smith There sure is.  I got it working by adding a route with `(.*)` as the path.  Make that an answer and I'll mark it correct.